# Forma geometricas com css

Tags: html, css, aplicação-web

Tenho pesquisado sobre o assunto, mas não sei muito sobre css e estou com duvidas de como fazer essa forma.

Uma das maneiras que achei foi dessa forma

HTML e CSS

```css
.coracao {
   position: absolute;
}
.circulo-1 {
      border-top-left-radius: 0;
      border-top-right-radius: 0;

      width: 200px;
      margin-top: 0px;
      height: 300px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      box-shadow: rgb(255, 208, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="coracao">
   <div class="circulo-1"></div>
</div>
```

Porem não sai dessa forma, todas as maneiras que faço não se estabiliza da maneira que quero!

No espaço em branco ira entrar uma logo da empresa de exemplo!

- eu estou tentando com uma unica  fazer ela ficar desta forma,
- não sei se é sobre posto
- se tiver algo sobre posto, deve ser possível colocar uma logo em cima,

ja pensei em faser a imagem e por no lugar, mas preciso que o site também seja responsivo, a parte responsiva ja consegui fazer, porem essa forma para fica no canto da tela não estou conseguindo fazer e gostaria da ajuda de quem sabe CSS para me mostrar alguns comandos de como poderia fazer esse formato, sei que é possível fazer imagens magnificas com CSS, mas ainda não sou tão pratico pois estou aprendendo!

Materia de pesquisa usada por mim:
https://www.maujor.com/tutorial/css3-funcao-css-calc.php
https://www.maujor.com/tutorial/propriedades-css-para-estilizacao-de-bordas.php
https://helabs.com/artigos/2014/11/14/o-poder-do-css-3-desenhando-formas/
https://www.w3schools.com/css/

Quem puder ajudar fico grato.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Duvidas de como é o layout por completo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não testei isso... Mas da uma olhada nessa extensão do Chrome: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/css-shapes-editor/nenndldnbcncjmeacmnondmkkfedmgmp?hl=pt-BR

Comment: Caro @CelsoMarigoJr entendo sua boa intenção, o problema é que não dá para saber se o "corte" é no elemento em laranja (um div, logo quadrado), ou seja se o corte é interno, não dá para saber se é um objeto sobreposto, não dá para ter ideia alguma do que ele quer de fato e uma solução assim pode ser na verdade o caminho **não ideal** para o resultado desejado, seria melhor esperar ele revisar/editar a pergunta, as vezes especular é bom, outras vezes não

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento correto, concordo. É que eu entendo que as vezes o cara precisa de uma dica rápida, só quis ajudar. Mas entendo que a intenção da comunidade é gerar conhecimento, e esse tipo de pergunta não atende a este proposito.

Comment: Como poderia ter feito a pergunta?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Poderia me ajudar em como poderia fazer uma publicação?

Comment: Desculpe Samuel, o que você disse não esta claro ainda, o que seria "publicação"? Se esta se referindo a melhorar a pergunta, recomendo que leia: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, entenda bem o que é necessário e como deve se pergunta e então só depois disto edite a pergunta para podermos lhe ajudar.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Isso que fiz não foi uma publicação referente a uma divida que tenho sobre o css?

Comment: Samuel vc precisa ter conteúdo dentro da parte branca, essa parte seria um container de conteúdo? Seria apenas um background? A parte branca na verdade é transparente, vai ter algo aparecendo ali por traz como por exemplo a cor do body?  Esses são detalhes que fazem toda a diferença para poder te responder. Então explique melhor o que realmente precisa, assim vc não perde tempo com respostas que não te servem e a gente não perde tempo te respondendo algo que não é exatamente o que vc precisa... Se vc editar a sua pergunta com mais detalhas a comunidade pode Votar para Reabri-la :)

Comment: Caro Samuel, não foi não (uma pergunta de CSS), foi algo **vago**, que não dá para saber o que exatamente precisa e sua corrida aqui foi baseado em **preciso de uma solução qualquer para resolver um trabalho pessoal**, o que não é escopo do site, já que não fazemos o trabalho de ninguém, oque fazemos é buscar e responder com boas soluções para perguntas que estejam bem elaboradas, com todo perdão, a sua pergunta no momento é impossivel de dizer qual o caminho ideal para resolver, porque realmente podem ser inumeras maneiras e nenhuma delas pode ser o que lhe atende.

Comment: @hugocsl obrigado, irei fazer as alterações, muito obragado

Comment: @Guilherme Nascimento Ta bom, vou revisar, mas antes irei ver a extenção que o @ Celso Marigo Jr me sugeriu pois pode ser util. Mesmo assim Obrigado a todos

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento fiz uma revisão, o que acha agora? esta melhor?

Comment: Creio que os links ali não tem sentido algum e independente de apresentar algum código ou não continua sem ser possivel determinar as duvidas que citei em meu primeiro comentário, 1. se é um corte no laranja, 2. se é algo sobreposto, 3. se o sobreposto deve ser limitado ao laranja 4. terá outros elementos envolvidos. Mas creio que logo você conseguirá expressar a necessidade.Seria legal mesmo se vc der uma lida no link que lhe enviei sobre "exemplo minimo do problema", ou seja demonstrar o como "ele não estabiliza"

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento 1.Eu estou tentando com uma unica <div> fazer ela ficar desta forma, 2.não sei se é sobre posto 3. se tiver algo sobre posto, deve ser possível colocar uma logo em cima, 4.dependendo de como ser posto as <div>

Comment: Entendo Samuel, mas realmente se ler o link que lhe passei vai entender que não adianta escrever um bocado e comentar, tem que editar a pergunta e deixar ela clara e limpa, e apresentar de forma "funcional" como o problema ocorre explicar de forma simples e clara o problema, sem ficar com rodeios sobre "ajuda", "tempo é sensivel", a forma que esta apresentada complica apenas, espero que eu esteja conseguindo lhe guiar, preciso ir agora, mais tarde volto para ver como esta, talvez consiga lhe ajudar.

Comment: @SamuelSampaio acho que se vc tiver uma imagem de como vc gostaria do *layout final* algo que o designer ou o cliente te passou, ou que vc mesmo tenha feito ou esboçado, pode ajudar a te responder. A gente quer ajudar, só quer evitar de responder algo que não é o que vc quer e ter que ficar refazendo resposta até adivinhar o que de fato precisa. As vezes com uma imagem do layout final pode ajudar.

Comment: @hugocsl layout final ja esta no post

Comment: Agora sim jovem!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vc pode usar `radial-gradiente` para fazer essa forma, o resultado fica bem fiel a imagem e vc ainda tem a vantagem da transparência caso quera deixa visível a cor de fundo do container.

Aqui vc pode ler mais sobre o `radial-gradiente`: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient

Modelo aplicando essa técnica, repare que tem uma `div` com classe `.topo` e dentro dela eu tenho um `<img>` com `position:absolute` que vai ser a logo alinhada no `bottom/right`. Já o `radial-gradiente` está como `background` dessa `div.topo` com a logo dentro. ***OBS:*** Vc pode brincar com os valores do `background-size` e `background-position` até achar algo que te agrade mais.

```css
html, body {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
aside {
 width: 200px;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: silver;
}
.topo {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 200px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 background-image: radial-gradient(closest-side at 60% 55%, transparent 49%, rgb(177, 123, 6) 49.5%, #C88D16 52%, #FDD371 85%);
    background-size: 320% 250%;
    background-position: 60% 30%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.topo img {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 10px;
 right: 10px;
 width: 80px;
 height: auto;
}
```

```html
<aside>
 <div class="topo">
  <img src="https://placecage.com/100/100">
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <img src="https://placecage.com/20/20">
  <span>Lorem, ipsum.</span>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <img src="https://placecage.com/20/20">
  <span>Lorem, ipsum.</span>
 </div>
</aside>
```

Comment: Show cara, muito obrigado. Testei aqui funcionou do jeitinho que preciso!

Muito Obrigado, vou estudar a matéria que me passou

Comment: @SamuelSampaio que bom que deu certo, foi difícil arredondar a pergunta, mas isso tb serve como aprendizado né. Não deixe de ler o link e pesquisar mais sobre linear-gradient, essa técnica ajuda em vários casos, com certeza vc vai precisar dela novamente no futuro. []´s